# REST API using Civetweb and Lua

Tags: rest, lua

So, my task is to develop web application using the following technologies:

1. Angular on front end,
2. On back end, I will use civetweb as stand-alone web server (https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb) and Lua (or C if Lua doesn't fit well),
3. Sqlite3 (http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki)

After a certain amount of time spend on the research about this topic (back end side), I am not sure what are the best practices for this, due to the fact that I couldn't find useful examples, except for the official documentation on civetweb github repository.

Specifically, I am not sure what is the best way: to handle requests/responses, structure the code (the main server logic, the part of the system which is in the charge of working with database, etc.)

I would appreciate any suggestions, links to examples or useful documentation, etc.

P.S. I am used to object-oriented world, and that is the main cause of my problems.